# Почему не работает символ "десятичная точка" в регулярном выражении?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Почему не работает символ "десятичная точка" в регулярном выражении?
`.` - (десятичная точка) соответствует любому символу кроме переноса строки.

```
    var reg2 = /([\s.]+$)/ig;
    var match2;

    while (match2 = reg2.exec("drgdrgdgdrgdgr       ыуаыуаыуа
ыуаыаыа")) {
           console.log(match2[1]); 
          }
```

Результат - не находит символы согласно десятичнной точке.

Необходимо чтобы находило строку согласно `.` и символу `\s`
Вот примерно так - `/([,\w!\s]+)$/ig`

Только как то так - `/([.\s]+)$/ig` - но десятичный символ `.` не работает в [].

---

вот выражеие которое работает - /([,А-Яа-я\w!\s]+)$/ig Нужно тоже самое только с десятичной точкой. Зачем мне перечислять все символы между [] , которые поддерживает точка.

---

**1.** Этот скрин демонстрирует выражение которое составил я (так должно работать)  -

`/([,А-Яа-я\w!\s]+)$/ig`

Это рабочий пример - [Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ezgefzjy/2)

[Картинка с правильной работой выражения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlTL9.jpg)

```
        var reg2 = `/([,А-Яа-я\w!\s]+)$/ig`;
        var match2;

        while (match2 = reg2.exec("Тест А сейчас будет перенос на новую строку
это наш текст на новой строке")) {
               console.log(match2[1]); 
         }
```

**2.** Вариант (это не верно) -

`/(\s+|.+)$/ig`

[Демо кода 1](https://jsfiddle.net/dfeooyak/)

[Картинка с неправильной работой выражения номер 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is3Kx.jpg)

```
        var reg2 = `/(\s+|.+)$/ig`;
        var match2;

        while (match2 = reg2.exec("Тест А сейчас будет перенос на новую строку
это наш текст на новой строке")) {
               console.log(match2[1]); 
         }
```

**3.** Вариант (это не верно) -

`/(\s+|.+)$/igm`

[Картинка с неправильной работой выражения номер 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO61f.jpg)

```
        var reg2 = `/(\s+|.+)$/igm`;
        var match2;

        while (match2 = reg2.exec("Тест А сейчас будет перенос на новую строку
это наш текст на новой строке")) {
               console.log(match2[1]); 
         }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40309/discussion-on-question-by-gilo1212------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутри `[]` точка расценивается не как спецсимвол, а как символ точки, поэтому данное регулярное выражение ищет текст состоящий из точек и пробельных символов.

Для решения можно отказаться от `[]`, в пользу `|` например так

```js
var reg2 = /(\s+|.+)$/ig;
var match2;

while (match2 = reg2.exec("rgrgr rgrgrg             rgrgrgrgrg")) {
  console.log(match2[1]);
}
```

**Upd.** для добавленного примера, можно убрать ограничение строки `$`

```js
var $text_area = $('textarea'),
  htmlParser,
  chat_description2_preview = $('.chat_description2-preview');

function check() {
  chat_description2_preview.text("");
  tested($text_area.val());
}

$text_area.on('input propertychange', check);

function tested(text) {
  var reg2 = /(.+|\s+)/ig;
  var match2;

  while (match2 = reg2.exec(text)) {
    if (match2[1] != undefined) { //ссылка в конце строки или просто строка без изображения
      chat_description2_preview.append(match2[1]);
      console.log(match2[1]);
    }
  }
}

check();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Пример номер 1</div>
<textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text">
Тест А сейчас будет перенос на новую строку 
это наш текст на новой строке 
и еще раз 
и еще 
и опять 
и снова
</textarea>
<span></span>

<div style="white-space: pre;" id="con_pred" class='chat_description2-preview'></div>
```

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос. К сожалению но Ваш варинат работать не будет. Не учитывает переход на новую строку.

Comment: @gilo1212, добавьте в вопрос входные и выходные данные, для которых текущее выражение на подходит

Comment: @gilo1212, чтобы выражение в ответе работало с учетом перевода строки, надо убрать в конце символ конца строки `$`

Comment: @iksuy, Не обязательно, можно еще один флаг добавить, но без _конкретного_ примера от автора с ожидаемым результатом, можно только гадать что он хотел увидеть :)

Comment: @Grundy, да, действительно, флаг `m` решает проблему

Comment: @iksuy Я же пример привел, роабочего выражения. Я не могу понять, что еще нужно. Может быть видео снять?

Comment: @iksuy Не решает. Только от части. Но нет, же.

Comment: Второй комментарий к ответу, приведите пример входных данных, на которых не работает выражение из данного ответа. Если это пример из обновленного ответа (с русскими буквами и переводом строки), то добавив флаг `m` выражение из ответа найдет ваш пример.

Comment: @gilo1212, да, видео было бы в самый раз, если вы не может добавить в вопрос пример, в котором ваше выражение и выражение в ответе дают разный результат

Comment: @Grundy Я выложил картинки и примеры. Видео мне делать?

Comment: @gilo1212, картинки вижу, примеров не вижу.

Comment: @Grundy Добавил. Или польностью в  HTML странице  пример выложить, три таких страницы?

Comment: @gilo1212, вы можете добавлять сниппеты в вопрос, такой же как я добавил в ответ. На данный момент код который показан в блоках кода  выдает ошибку _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL_

Comment: @Grundy Сейчас делаю